# Problem in creating a countdown in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am creating a countdown in **Typescript** that will set an alarm.
I have taken input from the time attribute and then converted it by using .getTime and subtracted the current .getTime and displayed the result in console. When the time passes, the difference is not zero. [Difference on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh9SA.png)

```
var timer = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("time")).valueAsNumber; //getting input of time element and
    console.log(timer);
    console.log(new Date().getTime())

    setInterval(function () { //a timer
        var duration = (timer - (new Date().getTime()))/1000;
        console.log(duration);
        if (duration=0){
        document.querySelector("audio").play();//plays audio
        clearInterval();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is setting the duration to 0 rather than checking with `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is not going to be exact, and also there is some small amount of time needed for executing `new Date().getTime())`.

To get the timer to work as intended, you can check if it's within a tolerance: `if (duration < 10)` instead of checking if it's exactly 0.

Alternatively, you can use `setTimeout` since you're only executing the function once.

Comment: I am displaying the difference each second in the console that is why I have used setInterval